Communicate BLE in OnApplicationPause
unity is working on a project related to BLE communication.
If Unity is forced to shut down, the BLE device must also shut down.
However, it seems that BLE communication is not working because the game thread is terminated at the time of OnApplicationPause.
Is there any other method?
private void OnApplicationPause(bool pauseStatus)
{
    if (pauseStatus)
    {
        WriteCharacteristic("{\"desired\":{\"power\":false}}");
    }
}

For your information, your device is Oculus.
I hope that BLE device will also be shut down when it is forced to shut down.
